# Dual Booting Linux Distributions

Tags: boot, system

So I decided I want to build my own LFS system on the same drive of my Ubuntu partition. I want to mount the LFS system but I do not know where the proper place to mount it at. Should I mount it as `/` (root) or someplace else like desktop with a symbolic link or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

From LFS guide:

> LFS is usually installed on a dedicated partition. The recommended
>   approach to building an LFS system is to use an available empty
>   partition or, if you have enough unpartitioned space, to create one

So after you have made partitions using tools such as GParted or `fdisk`, you'll have to create filesystem on the that partition (possibly `ext4` and `swap`) using `mkfs`.

**Where to mount?**

Now, you can mount the parition anywhere you like, but if you are following the LFS book it will be easier for you if you mount the new parition at `/mnt/lfs`.

Read chapters 2.2 to 2.5 in the LFS [book](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/index.html). It is described nicely there.

Comment: That slipped right through my memory. I was concerned because Gparted had "mounted" grayed out.

Comment: But I did do those steps.